# Visual Studio Community 2017 Wont Start

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I already installed VS 2017 Community in my PC and when I run it, it wont start at all and will only beep an error sound. What could be the problem on this?

Thank you.

Comment: Try running it as an administrator

Comment: I already tried it and got the same outcome @preciousbetine

Comment: Go to your desktop, press the windows key and the letter `R` key simultaneously to start `RUN` then type in `devenv` and hit enter. If visual studio was properly installed, it should run else you have to grab a new copy.

Comment: or check in Task Manager and make sure the Visual Studio installer is not running and/or stalled.